# A form inserted through ActionCable wont verify

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, csrf, actioncable

I have a setup where User A rejects User B's offer. This triggers ActionCable to push a form created using `button_to` to User B informing him of this, and let's him click the message to delete it. But the form raises `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken`

`params {"_method"=>"delete", "authenticity_token"=>"4lqu8...", "id"=>"31"}`

I do have another form which I replace a `create` form with an `update` form using ActionCable and it works fine. So, my attempt was to change the flow to when User A rejects the offer it triggers User B to request the message. And for that I moved the logic from a service object to

```
class AuctionOwnChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    #...
  end

  def display(hash)
    ActionCable.server.broadcast "auction_own_channel_#{params[:oPId]}_#{current_user.id}", hash
  end

  # In the code below `rack_inputs` is passed into `frustrated_replacement` and the subsequent methods to reach `render`
  def rejected(data)
    info = data["info"]
    display BidServices::Process.frustrated_replacement(info["product_id"], info["message_id"], current_user)
  end
end

module BidServices
  class Process
    class << self
      def frustrated_replacement(product_id, message_id, user)
        message = Message.find message_id
        thing = {partial: "messages/rejected", locals: {message: message}}
        replacements(thing, user)
      end

      def replacements(thing, user)
        { processed_bid: render(thing),
          cart: render(partial: "bids/cart", locals: {current_user: user} )
        }
      end

      def render(*args)
        a_c = ApplicationController
        a_c.per_form_csrf_tokens = true # Have tried with and without this
        a_c.renderer.render(*args)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

EDIT: Since writing this I did further research and went through some of the code for ActionView and I think I need to set the session

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user, :rack_inputs

    def connect
      self.rack_inputs  = find_rack_inputs
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
      logger.add_tags 'ActionCable', current_user.id
    end

    protected
    def find_rack_inputs
      # I just tried adding `session` in the hash but it did not help
      {input: env["rack.input"], http_host: env['HTTP_HOST'], session: env["rack.session"]} 
    end

   # Attempt to replace whole env
   # def find_rack_inputs
      # env 
   # end
  end
end


module BidServices
  class Process
      def render(*args)
        rack_inputs = args.pop
        controller = MessagesController
        renderer = controller.renderer.new(rack_inputs)
        renderer.render(*args)
      end

      # The changes when I was replacing the env
      # def render(*args)
      #   rack_inputs = args.pop # This attempt rack_inputs was `env`
      #   MessagesController.renderer.new(rack_inputs).render(*args)
      # end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: In our case, the simplest was to disable csrf (skip_before_action :verify_authenticity, only: [xx]) for the particular action that we triggered by a bg-job.
The CSRF are validated against the session, always! So if we want AC.renderer to generate valid forms, we need to pass the whole session into it somehow, by passing the session stuff around - https://dev.to/mepatterson/getting-rails-applicationcontroller-renderer-to-render-images-and-know-about-the-rack-session-2205